# Using a DataOutput/Input Stream with Netty?

Tags: java, networking, io, netty, nio

I'm attempting to venture into non-blocking networking using Java and I had decided on using the Netty Networking Library to do so. I currently have a fully working server/client application that uses Strings to handle the networking functions. The server/client will dissasemble the strings and get the data from it; However this is not what I need to be doing.

I've been looking at the DataOutputStream and it seems it has the functions that I would like to be able to use over a network.

- writeByte/readByte
- writeBytes/readBytes
- writeChar/readChar
- writeDouble/readDouble
- writeShort/readShort
- writeFloat/readFloat
- writeInt/readInt
- writeUTF/readUTF.

Currently everything I've been doing has been in UTF Format, basically. I've just been sending bytes using (bytes[])String

I'm having a very hard time figuring out how to implement a system like this. I don't want to continue using this inefficient string based networking. It's a waste of bandwidth and I'm not learning anything doing it.

Comment: You could design your own protocol with headers, payload, etc. what does your program do?

Comment: @Kayaman -- I don't really understand networking all that much, I'm just getting into it. I'm working on a 2D game as a hobbyist project before I start school. `EDIT: I understand networking, just not the code behind it... If I knew how to write my own protocol I wouldn't be asking for help :P`

Comment: You should look at some existing protocols then. Maybe you'll get ideas. `DataStreams` are quite useful, you're right, since usually you'll have different size fields in the header and it's way easier to read them with the different methods, than as a byte array and parse it yourself.

Comment: What you are looking for is probably something like Thrift/Nifty and Swift? https://github.com/facebook/swift/

Answer (score 0):

So, I found what I was looking for built into netty, I've been using it for a few days now and haven't posted back.

Inside of netty there is a `ChannelBufferInputStream` and a `ChannelBufferOutputStream` these both take in the ChannelBuffer as a parameter and allow similar functions to that of a DataStream. It has really helped me with my networking.